# SonarQube 6.4 web api get new violations only as a XML

Tags: xml, sonarqube

How can i get the new issues introduced since the last analysis as a **xml** from the sonar web api ? 
I know that we can use the **createdAt** key in the latest version to get the latest issues. But i want to know is there any other way to get it by just passing 
a key word like **new_violations**. This was there in version 6.0 
**metrics=new_violations**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues introduced on the leak period can be loaded by calling  `api/issues/search?sinceLeakPeriod=true&...`. See https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search,  https://blog.sonarsource.com/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/ and https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak for more details.

About the question on XML, Web API does support only JSON in responses.

Comment: It was supported in version 6.0. Anyway what about getting new violations ?

Comment: Thanks ! This is helpful.

Comment: More than deprecated : dropped !